# How to dispose or remove the overlay from a separate class?

Tags: flutter, class, methods, overlay

Please help!

I have initiated the overlay from a separate class, (calling the showOverlay) now I am trying to close the same overlay by calling dispose or remove but without much success. Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong and the best way to close the over from a separate class?

Below is a snippet of my code (its quite long)

```
class RootApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RootAppState createState() => RootAppState();

}

class RootAppState extends State<RootApp> {
  bool isFavorite = false;
  int pageIndex = 0;

  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  PageController _pgController = PageController();

  //For search
  late OverlayState? overlayState;
  late OverlayEntry overlayEntry;

  void pgCont(pg){
    print(pg);
    if(_pgController.hasClients) {
      _pgController.animateToPage(
          pg, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
    }
    print(_pgController.hasClients);
    setState(() {

    });

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;


    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: PageView(controller: _pgController,
          children: <Widget>[
            getMovieBody(),
            getTvBody(),
      ]),

      bottomNavigationBar: getFooter(),
    );
  }


  showOverlay(BuildContext){
    final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final searchOverlaySize = renderBox.size;
    overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context)=>Positioned(
      top: 0.0,
      width: searchOverlaySize.width,
      height: searchOverlaySize.height/3,
      child: getSearchBox(),

    ),);

    overlayState?.insert(overlayEntry);
  }

  void hideOverlay() {
    print('trying to dispose');
  // overlayEntry.remove(); //LateInitializationError: Field 'overlayEntry' has not been initialized.
  //  overlayEntry.dispose(); //LateInitializationError: Field 'overlayEntry' has not been initialized.
    overlayState?.dispose(); // Error LateInitializationError: Field 'overlayState' has not been initialized.
    overlayState = null;
  }
```

I'm trying to use the following to call the hideOverlay from the class searchbox..

```
final RootAppState roots = new RootAppState();

roots.hideOverlay();
```

What Im I doing wrong or is there an easier way to call the destroy or remove the overlay? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GlobalKey` to fulfill your requirement.

```
// define globalKey where other class have access(eg. top level scope)
GlobalKey<DemoWidgetState> globalKey = GlobalKey();

// use globelKey in RootAppState
Scaffold(
  key: globalKey
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  body: PageView(controller: _pgController, children: <Widget>[
    getMovieBody(),
    getTvBody(),
  ]),
  bottomNavigationBar: getFooter(),
);

// call hideOverlay form other class
globalKey.currentState?.hideOverlay();
```

Comment: Would this approach work if calling hideOverlay is in a separate dart file and simply using an import to gain access to the method?

Comment: Yes. Calling `hideOverlay` is in a separate dart file(using an import to gain access to the method) will work as excepted.